# windows service could not connect to service controller 1063 error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-services, system-tray

I'm trying to start and stop the windows service programatically using a notify tray icon. The service and the System Tray Icon App can talk over Named pipes IPC. So, I took this example from [msdn](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppWindowsService-cacf4948) and added IPC schemes to it. This service on starting, installs himself (create service method) successfully. Now I don't call him to start from services.msc.

Instead the Tray Icon pings the service and service pongs back. Then, the Tray ICon sends a start command. Upon receiving the start command, the service has to kick off him self and start running.

On Start Request from tray icon,  I'm calling run service method in the example, which has the service table and service control dispatcher in it (I assume, the service control dispatcher will trigger a call onstart method from windows). But the service control dispatcher return the 1063 error. I tried with admin privileges and moving him to secure account etc., nothing worked.

Can someone help me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Attached is the source code for reference [link] (http://pastebin.com/WDdBJH2e).

Comment: Your description is confusing. You say the service installs itself when it starts - but how can it start when it's not installed? How can it respond to pings from the tray icon when it's not running? You seem to be trying to violate causality here.

Comment: Sorry for confusing. The service program is executed this way: 'service.exe -install'. Then, the service program does two things. It installs the service (by using the create service method, in Thread1, waits in while(GetMessage(...)) and also kicks of the named pipes to wait for connections (thread2). The named pipes thread will be responsible for pings, pongs etc., when tray icon sends start command, named pipes receive first and posts the message to thread1 to start service. Thread1 will then call Run method(contains service table and service dispatcher). So, it fails here with err:1063.

Comment: One starts a service by calling - wait for it - `StartService`. It doesn't sound like you ever do that. I don't understand this whole named-pipes-ping-pong dance. Can't the tray app just call `StartService` to start your service, and `ControlService[Ex]` to stop it?

Comment: The reason for the tray icon ping-pong is that tray icon stays in the user Desktop and windows service runs in the different session. They are now segregated with session isolation. Hence some IPC scheme to talk with each other. I actually have core engine with service and need to have full duplex communication with tray icon. I  just took an example from msdn and started forking it as per requirement. So that I don't need to sweat a lot. I just looked into StartService and related functions, I will check around how they can help me.

Comment: The service controller - as represented by `StartService` and `ControlService` API - **is** an IPC mechanism designed specifically for an interactive application to start and stop a service. Once the service is started, **then** talk to it using named pipes and what not. In any case, when you run `service.exe` manually - as you say you do - it does not run in a different session: it's an interactive application like any other. When you call `StartService`, the service manager will run another copy of `service.exe`, in session 0. Apparently, that's what you want.

Comment: Looks Cool solution. I feel it works good this way. One more question,  Now I have tray and service as two different applications. How do yo think integrating the both the programs work? Like for instance, writing tray and service in one App (still IPC enabled for later talks). While launching the tray we install a service. The tray can `StartService`, `ControlService` directly and if needed talk over pipes. I don't know what happens when we reboot the machine? the service still remains on reboot. How goes it with tray? I'm new in this, sorry if its too dumb question!

Comment: It worked happily with the `StartService` and `StopService` functions. Tray can now start and stop services, Thanks for the help :)